# Why does my mouse go out of the window's border when playing my games?

Tags: games

I got a game called oopenlugaru and it can't go fullscreen, which is ok, but my mouse always misbehaves and goes out of the border. I know there's an easy solution to this. Can anyone refresh my mind please?